# How do I make independently compiled cython packages use a shared random number generator?

Tags: python, c, cython, cythonize

I have an experimental programming language where programs are compiled to c. I've written a cython wrapper that wraps around the compiled c code and allows it to be callable from python. This lets you use compiled programs as fast low-level functions from within python. It's often the case that we want to use multiple such programs within the same python program. Then the pipeline for generating and importing each program is:

1. Compile the program to c using the compiler.
2. Compile the c code to a .so shared object using gcc.
3. Generate a .pyx wrapper which can access the c functions we want to use from python.
4. Compile the .pyx wrapper with cythonize to generate a .so.
5. Import the .so shared object using python's import feature.

In practice, steps 1-4 are actually merged into a single external call to make using sys, with a generated Makefile performing each of the 4 steps. This lets us call make via an external call with sys and then import the compiled program without ever leaving python.

A compiled program may have probabilistic constructs. In particular, branching decisions are governed by random numbers. To do this, calls are made to c's native

```
rand()
```

function. When a wrapper compiled program is imported in python, an import call is made to the generated .so shared object which is produced using cythonize. So far I've tried calling

```
srand(<long int>time(NULL)
```

from within the .pyx file that wraps each compiled program. As far as I can tell, each imported .so will effectively be using its own random number generator. But it's not at all clear to me from the docs whether this is the case.

Ultimately I want the different .so's to be using the same random number generator, but I have no idea how to go about this. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Much of the code is too long to include here, but if you'd like to see any snippets (e.g. 'how do you do x component?') I will happily oblige.

Even if all you can offer is an explanation of how calls to rand() will interact between different shared objects generated with cythonize, that might give me enough to work out a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can check it via `nm my_extension.so | grep rand`, if `rand@@GLIB_XXX` has attribute `U` (most probably), then it will be provided by `libc.so` and the state is shared between all modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it's well-defined in the C specification whether the random seed is shared between .so files or individual (that said - I haven't read the C standard, so I'm guessing slightly here). Therefore what behaviour you see *may* depend on the platform you're on.

The simplest thing here would be to write a small Cython module that's sole purpose is to handle random number generation:

```
# cy_rand.pxd
cpdef void srand(unsigned int)
cpdef int rand()

# cy_rand.pyx
from libc cimport stdlib

cpdef void srand(unsigned int seed):
    stdlib.srand(seed)

cpdef int rand():
    return stdlib.rand()
```

I've made the functions `cpdef` so that you can call them from Python too. If you don't care about being able to do this then just make them `cdef`.

You need to compile this module in the normal way. In your other modules you can just do:

```
cimport cy_rand

cy_rand.srand(1) # some seed
rand_val = cy_rand.rand()
```

This way you know that random numbers are only being generated in one .so file. This adds a small layer of indirection so will be slightly slower than just calling it directly. Therefore it might be a good idea to add helper functions to generate random numbers in bulk (for speed).

Be aware that other libraries could call `srand` or `rand` themselves, and because it's possibly global state this could affect you - this is one of the reasons why the C standard library random number generator isn't hugely robust...

Comment: I think it is not for the standard to decide, whether `rand` is in a shared library or not: when the extension is linked it can be linked agains a shared version of libc or agains a static version (which is quite unusual but possible).

Comment: It is a very solid advice, as later on, one could easily replace the `rand/srand` pair through c++11's random generator or roll out a handmade one.